# Branch version editing in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

I'm trying to figure out if you can publish a particular version for users to edit on an ArcGIS Online map in a branch versioned environment. It doesn't look like there is a way to select the version on Portal that you use in your web map. It only makes edits to the default version when I test it in an ArcGIS Online map. I know that you can publish a specific version to Portal/AGOL in traditional versioning and it is really handy because you can compare edits done to that version by, say, a field worker editing on a mobile device, with the default version in the office instead of automatically committing those edits to the default version.

Can this be done with branch versioning?

Answer (score 0):

No this can't be done with branch versioning

Answer (score 0):

Yep, put a branch version feature service in a map in pro, create the version you want and publish the map.  Then you have a webmap with the versioned feature service.